# Problema renderizado imagen

Tags: java

Estoy desarrollando un programa, en el que un cañón dispara una bala, y esta impacta en un punto determinado del mapa. El problema está en que cuando giro el cañón para cambiar la dirección de disparo, hay un problema de renderizado:

[image: Salida del programa]

No hay ningún panel que interfiera, a priori. Os muestro el código a continuación para que tengáis todo detalle:

**Interfaz gráfica**

```
package elementosJuego;

    import elementosJuego.paneles.PanelCanon;
    import elementosJuego.paneles.PanelMapaCanon;
    import java.awt.Color;
    import java.awt.Dimension;
    import java.awt.FlowLayout;
    import java.awt.Graphics;
    import java.awt.Graphics2D;
    import java.awt.GridLayout;
    import java.awt.Rectangle;
    import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
    import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
    import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
    import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
    import javax.swing.*;
    import javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicProgressBarUI;

        /**
         *
         * @author ignacioaranguren
         */
        public class Juego extends JFrame {
            private Casilla[][] mapa;
            private JPanel contenedorTiempo, contenedorVidas,contenedorBarra;
            private PanelMapaCanon contenedorMapaCanon;
            private PanelCanon contenedorCanon;
            private Dimension d1, d2, d3, d4, d5;
            private double anguloRotacion = Math.PI/2, anguloMin = 0.656173986, anguloMax = 2.485418668;
            private JProgressBar barra;
            private ActionListener ac ;
            private Timer t;
            private int progreso = 0;
            private boolean flag = false;

            public Juego(){

                setLayout(null);
                setBackground(Color.black);
                d1 = new Dimension(646, 699);
                contenedorMapaCanon = new PanelMapaCanon(d1);
                contenedorMapaCanon.setBounds(0, 0, 646, 699);

                barra = new JProgressBar(JProgressBar.HORIZONTAL, 0, 100);


                barra.setBorder(new javax.swing.border.LineBorder(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0), 2, true));
                barra.setUI(new BasicProgressBarUI(){
                    @Override
                    protected void paintDeterminate(Graphics g, JComponent c) {
                        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
                        int ancho = barra.getWidth();
                        int alto = barra.getHeight();

                        int espacioAncho = ancho ;
                        int espacioAlto = alto ;
                        barra.setPreferredSize( new Dimension(200,40));
                        double porcentajeProgres = barra.getPercentComplete();

                        espacioAncho = (int)(espacioAncho * porcentajeProgres);
                        if(porcentajeProgres <= 0.25){
                            g2d.setColor(Color.GREEN);
                        }else if( porcentajeProgres > 0.25 && porcentajeProgres <= 0.5){
                            g2d.setColor(Color.yellow);
                        }else if( porcentajeProgres > 0.5 && porcentajeProgres <= 0.75){
                            g2d.setColor(Color.orange);
                        }else{
                            g2d.setColor(Color.red);
                        }
                        Rectangle rec1 = new Rectangle(0,0, espacioAncho, espacioAlto);
                        g2d.fill(rec1);
                    }

                 });
                 ac = new ActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        if(flag == false){
                        progreso = progreso + 1;
                        if(progreso == 99){
                            flag = true;
                        }
                        }else{
                            progreso = progreso - 1;
                            if(progreso == 1){
                                flag = false;
                            }
                        }
                        barra.setValue(progreso);
                    }

                };

                t = new Timer(20, ac);
                t.start();//cambiar el  final
                //add(barra);
                d2 = new Dimension(646, 120);
                contenedorCanon = new PanelCanon(d2);
                contenedorCanon.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT));
                //contenedorCanon.setBackground(Color.gray);
                contenedorCanon.setBounds(0, 700, 646, 120);
                d4 = new Dimension(100, 100);
                contenedorVidas = new JPanel();
                contenedorVidas.setBackground(Color.red);
                contenedorVidas.setSize(d4);



                d5 = new Dimension(100, 100);
                contenedorTiempo = new JPanel();
                contenedorTiempo.setBackground(Color.blue);
                contenedorTiempo.setSize(d5);
                addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
                    @Override
                    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent evento) {
                        switch (evento.getKeyCode()) {
                            case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:
                                if(anguloRotacion > anguloMin && anguloRotacion < anguloMax ){
                                    anguloRotacion = anguloRotacion + 0.05;
                                    contenedorCanon.setAngulo(anguloRotacion);
                                    contenedorCanon.repaint();
                                }
                                break;
                            case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:
                                if(anguloRotacion > anguloMin && anguloRotacion < anguloMax){
                                    anguloRotacion = anguloRotacion - 0.05;
                                    contenedorCanon.setAngulo(anguloRotacion);
                                    contenedorCanon.repaint();
                                }
                                break;
                        }
                       requestFocus();
                    }

                });
                add(contenedorMapaCanon);

                add(contenedorCanon);
                //contenedorCanon.add(barra);
                setSize(900,900);

                setVisible(true);

            }

            private void cambiarDireccion(){

            }
        }
```

En está clase inicializo todas las componentes, paneles, barras de progreso... He estado revisando el código y no veo que haya un problema con algún panel que esté interfiriendo con el cañón.

La segunda clase es la del contenedor del cañón, la cual hereda de JPanel.

En está clase realizo la rotación de del cañón. El escuchador (JPanel) recibe un evento de teclado. En la cual realizo un incremento del ángulo de rotación.

**Clase PanelCanon**

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package elementosJuego.paneles;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import java.awt.image.AffineTransformOp;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

import javax.swing.*;

/**
 *
 * @author ignacioaranguren
 */
public class PanelCanon extends JPanel{
    private double alfa = 0;
    private boolean flag = false;
    public PanelCanon(Dimension d){
        super.setSize(d);
        setBackground(Color.gray);
    }

    public void setAngulo(double alfa){
        this.alfa = Math.PI/2-alfa;
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        try {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d1 = (Graphics2D) g;
            BufferedImage img=ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/imagenes/canon.png"));
            //Image img  = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/imagenes/canon.png")).getImage();
            if(flag == true){

                double locationX = img.getWidth(this) / 2;
                double locationY = img.getHeight(this) / 2;
                AffineTransform tx = AffineTransform.getRotateInstance(alfa, locationX, locationY);
                AffineTransformOp op = new AffineTransformOp(tx, AffineTransformOp.TYPE_BILINEAR);
                tx.rotate(alfa);
                System.out.println(tx.toString());
                g2d1.drawImage(op.filter(img, null), 330,10, null);
            }else{
                g2d1.drawImage(img, 335,0, null);
                flag = true;
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(PanelCanon.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }


}
```

**Clase Mapa:**

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package elementosJuego.paneles;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

/**
 *
 * @author ignacioaranguren
 */
public class PanelMapaCanon extends JPanel{

    public PanelMapaCanon(Dimension d){
        super.setSize(d);
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        Image img = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/imagenes/fondoMapa.png")).getImage();
        g.drawImage(img, 30, 30, this); 
    }

}
```

Comment: ¿No será que estás despreciando sin querer el eje negativo de las `x` en la rotación? Haz una cosa, edita tu imagen `canon.png` y hazla cuadrada (mismo alto que ancho)

Comment: Lo he probado y nada. Aun así si fuese ese el caso, dado que el centro de rotación es el centro de la imagen, debería cortar la mitad de la imagen según la orientación.

Comment: ¿Cambia algo si le pones paréntesis a `Math.PI/2-alfa` para que sea `Math.PI/(2-alfa)` o tienes alguna forma de manejar división entre cero?

Answer (score 2):

No hay ningún error, es que funciona así. Algo igual me pasó en una aplicación C# y tras darle muchas vueltas lo que pasa es que la imagen rota su contenido sobre su propio canvas pero este sigue tal cual.

La solución que me sirvió a mi fue crear una imagen auxiliar a modo de canvas que sea justo el doble que la que quieres rotar. Luego sobre esta imagen auxiliar dibujas el cañon y luego aplicas la rotación a la imagen auxiliar.

```
Graphics2D g2d1 = (Graphics2D) g;
BufferedImage img=ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/imagenes/canon.png"));

int newSizeW2 = img.getWidth() * 2;
int newSizeH2 = img.getHeight() * 2;
BufferedImage imgAUX = new BufferedImage(newSizeW2, newSizeH2, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
// Obtenemos el Graphics para dibujar en imgAUX
Graphics gCanvas = imgAUX.getGraphics();
// Dibuja la imagen 'img' centrada en 'imgAUX'
gCanvas.drawImage(img, newSizeW2 / 4, newSizeH2 / 4, null);

// A partir de este punto aplica la rotación 
// a imgAUX y recuerda que las dimensiones es
// el doble que la del objeto inicial.
```